# Disable moderntimeline functionality without rewriting content

Tags: moderncv, moderntimeline

For some positions I'd like to apply to I'm not brave enough to use moderntimeline. Is it possible to disable the timeline part and fall back to just numerical date ranges without having to rewrite the relevant parts?

Comment: Hi McEnroe and [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this as you haven't provided a MWE, but the idea is to save two definitions of a cventry (`\cventrytl` and `\cventrynotl`) and switch your `\mycventry` between them.

So, in your preamble, save the two definitions:

```
\let\cventrynotl\cventry% save definition of cventry without timeline
\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\let\cventrytl\tlcventry% save definition of cventry with timeline

\let\mycventry\cventrytl% start with \mycventry as cventry with timeline
```

Then in your document, you can can simply use `\mycventry`, which takes the same arguments as `\tlcventry`. When you want to disable the timeline, you redefine it as follows to discard the two timeline arguments and resort to `\cventrynotl`:

```
\renewcommand*{\mycventry}[7]{\cventrynotl{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}}
```

When you want to reenable the timeline, you revert to the original definition:

```
\let\mycventry\cventrytl
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to the other answer, a helpful modification might be to use

`\renewcommand*{\mycventry}[7]{\cventrynotl{#1 -- \ifnum #2=0 ~ \else #2 \fi}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}}`

instead.